# Failed to open directory: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/block-template-utils.php:235

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, xampp, chromebook

This is my first time trying to put wordpress on my computer and I was trying to follow some steps on youtube on how to set it up. I tried giving the whole directory read, write, and execute permissions with chmod -R 777, but that didn't work. I got an error at 16:01 where the guy clicks the log in button on wordpress. Here is a link to the youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffGYlvBlLQY&t=957s .Here's the error message: [image]

This is the code for where the error is at:

```
if ( file_exists( $base_directory ) ) {
   235                  $nested_files      = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $base_directory ) );
   236                  $nested_html_files = new RegexIterator( $nested_files, '/^.+\.html$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH );
   237                  foreach ( $nested_html_files as $path => $file ) {
   238                          $path_list[] = $path;
   239                  }
   240          }
   241          return $path_list;
   242  }
```

Comment: @NorioYamamoto I tried emailing him and I commented in the Youtube section, but I haven't gotten a response back yet. I'll try following along with your Youtube video and tell you if I have any questions.

Comment: Did you forget to put sudo in front of chmod -R 777?

Comment: I didn't forget to put a sudo a in front. @Norio Yamamoto